# Which logs will tell me about the Touchpad and Keyboard locking up?

Tags: kernel, laptop, input-devices, modules, syslog

I have an Asus N53SM laptop that I leave running for several weeks at a time. I never put it in hibernate or suspend, I only close the lid when I'm not using it. After a few days or weeks of running, the touchpad and keyboard will Both lock up (at the same time) for no apparent reason. I could be just surfing the internet when it happens.

The touchpad and keyboard seem to only lock up when I'm actively using the laptop (not when idle), which may mean it's related to something I press, but I'm not sure? The touchpad never locks or unlocks when Pressing FN and the designated touchpad lock key (it does not seem to work on Linux).

While the touchpad and keyboard are locked, I am able to plug in my USB mouse and successfully use it to control the screen cursor. I can also remotely get into the system with vnc and ssh, everything seems to run fine there as well. No processes appear out of control. It's just the laptops physical touchpad and keyboard that are locking up.

How might I go about diagnosing this problem?

- What system logs to look at? (anything specific to look for in them?)
- Perhaps I should try reloading some modules?
- Any thing else I should inspect?

Comment: 1. What kind of laptop? 2. Cpu? 3. Ram? 4. Ubuntu Version? (32 or 64?) 5. How many USB devices? Is it well cooled? (Does it get hot)?